# is there a way to check if a FetchEvent comes from an iframe src?

Tags: iframe, fetch, service-worker

my serviceworker is listening on fetch, and for all the FetchEvent requests with navigate mode, i want to do something, but excluding the ones that come from iframes src.

I've inspected the event and the request objects and did not found a way to check it, is it possible to know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that information is not exposed in the [`FetchEvent`](https://w3c.github.io/ServiceWorker/#fetchevent-interface).

Additionally, there's no distinction made between full-page and `iframe` clients when determining the [`ClientType`](https://w3c.github.io/ServiceWorker/#enumdef-clienttype) value. Both come back with a `ClientType` of `window`.